# Devolver elementos de una lista que coincidan con parte de una palabra en Python

Tags: python, lista

mi problema es que tengo una lista con correos y quiero buscar un correo en la lista escribiendo una palabra algo así:

```
lista = [dreizmolina@gmail.com,jrodriguezgarcia@gmail.com]
palabra = 'reiz'
```

y que el resultado sea algo así:

```
el correo con esa palabra es dreizmolina@gmail.com
```

yo había intentado recorrer las dos listas con un for y me devuelve todas las letras parecidad:

```
lista = [dreizmolina@gmail.com,jrodriguezgarcia@gmail.com]
palabra = input('que palabra quieres buscar? ')
palabra = list(palabra)
    for correos in lista:
        correos = list(correos)
        for i in correos:
            for j in palabra:
                if i == j:
                    print(i)
```

y lo que me devuelve es esto:

```
r
e
i
z
i
e
e
r
r
i
e
z
r
i
e
e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for linea in lista:
    if palabra in linea:
        print(linea)
        break #si vas a buscar mas quita esto
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciona